# Explanation of if parameter in c++

Tags: c++

Considering the given part of a code . What does the following if statement does?

```
int* pItem;

 if(pItem)

 {
       pItem->getvalue();

  }
```

Comment: The code inside the `if` statement doesn't seem like it would compile, since `pItem` is an `int*` and the code inside the `if` statement seems like it's treating it as though it's a pointer to an object of some type.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, the if statement

```
if (pItem) { ... }
```

is equivalent to

```
if (pItem != nullptr) { ... }
```

In other words, it tests whether the pointer is null.

Generally speaking, if you see a non-boolean expression in an `if` statement, C++ will implicitly convert it to a `bool`. For pointers, this tests whether the pointer is null. For integer types, this tests whether the integer is 0. For object types, this tries to use an implicit conversion operator.

Answer (score 0):

> What does the following if statement does?

It invokes undefined behavior, since `pItem` is not initialized.

The

```
 if(pItem)
```

statement tries to avoid dereferencing `pItem`

```
 pItem->getvalue();
```

when `pItem` equals `0` or `nullptr`.

But as mentioned it's not initialized, hence it's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is that the if clause prevents the code from using a nullptr.

But, an int variable has no methods, so int->pItem is invalid in a different way.

I would expect in "int* pItem" that pItem is a pointer to a user define type (i.e. class).  But int is a reserved word, and thus a POD, with no methods.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ an expression evaluates to `false` if it is zero, otherwise it evaluates to `true`.

```
if (<expression>)
```

in this case `pItem` is the expression so we are testing whether it is zero (null) or not. It is equivalent to

```
if (pItem != nullptr)
```

You can think of it as saying "if pItem has a value (other than zero)"

Answer (score 0):

If that's all the code you have, then your program is subject to undefined behavior. You are using an uninitialized variable.

If the pointer is initialized properly, then it evaluates true/false in the if statement depending on what it points to. If it's value is nullptr or NULL, then it evaluates to false. Otherwise it evaluates to true.